# Can I inherit one Activity Designer from another in WF 4.0?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have created a activity designer in WF, i want to use that as a base for other activity designers.

When I try doing that, I get an compiler error - they are all partial classes and so I have to change the declaration of the base class at all locations.

Looking into the VS generated code I see that all other Activity designers inherit from the ActivityDesigner class.

Is there a way to have one activity designer from another?

PS: I dont think there is because usually an activity designer is bound to a Activity class by the "Designer" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you have XAML+code activity designer the base class is already specified in the XAML - it is `sap:ActivityDesigner` (on the first line).
So if you provide another base class in the code you are doing multiple inheritance and it doesn't work with C#.
Try to change the root tag of your XAML to something like this:

```
<local:MyBaseActivityDesigner xmlns:local="[your local assembly and namespace]" xmlns:...>
```

Then remove the base type from the code-behind.
This will set property your designer base type.

Of course there is a catch - you have to define the base designer in **code only**!
XAML+code designer can't be used as base types.